# BASH user drive selection

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am creating a simple script for mac os x to provide a user with a list of available drives to backup from based on the contents of /Volumes, but I am running into an issue with handling the output of the 'find' command if the drive name contains a space. The find command outputs each drive on a separate line, but the 'for each' breaks the name into parts. Example:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d
echo ""

i=1
for Output in $(find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
DriveChoice[$i]=$Output
echo $i"="${DriveChoice[$i]}
i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Output:

```
/Volumes
/Volumes/backup
/Volumes/EZBACKUP DRIVE
/Volumes/Tech

1=/Volumes
2=/Volumes/backup
3=/Volumes/EZBACKUP
4=DRIVE
5=/Volumes/Tech
logout

[Process completed]
```

This seems like it should be fairly straight-forward. Is there a better way for me to accomplish this?

Update: Thank you chepner, that works perfectly. It is a simple script to generate a ditto command, but I will post it here anyway in case someone finds any part of it useful:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get admin rights
sudo -l -U administrator bash
#Set the path to the backup drive
BackupPath="/Volumes/backup/"
#Generate a list of source drives, limiting out invalid options
i=1
while read -r Output; do
if [ "$Output" != "/Volumes" ] && [ "$Output" != "/Volumes/backup" ] && [ "$Output" != "/Volumes/Tech" ] ; then
    DriveChoice[$i]=$Output
    echo "$i=${DriveChoice[$i]}"
    i=$(( i+1 ))
fi
done < <( find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d)

#Have the user select from valid drives
echo "Source Drive Number?"
read DriveNumber
#Ensure the user input is in range
if [ $DriveNumber -lt $i ] && [ $DriveNumber -gt 0 ]; then
    Source=${DriveChoice[$DriveNumber]}"/"
    #Get the user's NetID for generating the folder structure
    echo "User's NetID?"
    read NetID
    NetID=$NetID
    #Grab today's date for generating folder structure
    Today=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
    #Destination for the Logfile
    Destination=$BackupPath$NetID"_"$Today"/"
    #Full path for the LogFile
    LogFile=$Destination$NetID"_log.txt"
    mkdir -p $Destination
    touch $LogFile
    #Destination for the backup
    Destination=$Destination"ditto/"
    #Execute the command
    echo "Processing..."
    sudo ditto "$Source" "$Destination" 2>&1 | tee "$LogFile"
else
    #Fail if the drive selection was out of range
    echo "Drive selection error!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot safely iterate over the output of `find` using a `for` loop, because of the space issue you are seeing. Use a `while` loop with the `read` built-in instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d
echo ""

i=1
while read -r output; do
    DriveChoice[$i]=$output
    echo "$i=${DriveChoice[$i]}"
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done < <( find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```